# Failed to parse Ephemeral Key.. CustomerSession.initCustomerSession stripe_sdk package

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I'm a bit confused abut how to initialise the package properly given the Stripe terminology.

App => my platform , which has an AccountId and a publishable key.
Account => any seller connected to my platform.
Customer => any buyer paying to my sellers.

As I first understood, I should initialise Stripe with my platform publishable key  and my platform `AccountId` as I saw the `stripeAccount` optional parameter, but the I saw the doc hint `acc_` so it was clear to initialise `Stripe` with a `CustomerId` contrarily to the `AccountId` .

But then I initialise the CustomerSession with api version ( I upgraded in console to the latest ) and customerId (same as above) but it trows an  `Unhandled Exception: Failed to parse Ephemeral Key, Please return the response as it is as you received from stripe server`  which is not picked by the catch statement.

Can you please help me clarify this? I 've looked around but haven't seen any explanation.
Many thanks.

Here's my inits, what am I doing wrong?:

```
try {
              Stripe.init(Environment.stripePublishableKey,
                  stripeAccount: state.user.stripeId);

              CustomerSession.initCustomerSession((apiVersion) async {
                print('apiVersion is : $apiVersion');
                return apiVersion;
              }, apiVersion: '2020-08-27', stripeAccount: state.user.stripeId);
            } catch (error) {
              print('Stripe error: $error');
            }
```

these are the prints from console:

```
I/flutter (26067): apiVersion is : 2020-03-02
E/flutter (26067): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Failed to parse Ephemeral Key, Please return the response as it is as you received from stripe server
E/flutter (26067): #0      EphemeralKeyManager.retrieveEphemeralKey (package:stripe_sdk/src/ephemeral_key_manager.dart:101:9)
E/flutter (26067): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26067): 
[log] FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 5)
2020-03-02
    ^
```

``

Comment: Log out what response your backend returns as your full raw EphemeralKey JSON. Is that a full EphemeralKey object? I assume it is inside `EphemeralKeyManager.retrieveEphemeralKey()` - referring to this section from the docs: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#set-up-ephemeral-key-client-side

Comment: @hmunoz I finally found out that I got it all wrong. 
I finally was able to initialise customerSession properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a better look at the method description

```
void initCustomerSession( 
Future<String> Function(String) provider,
{ String apiVersion = defaultApiVersion,
String stripeAccount,
bool prefetchKey = true,
})
```

I saw that I needed to create it using the Stipe api from my Node server:

```
stripe.ephemeralKeys.create({customer: customer}, {apiVersion: apiVersion})
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('Mongoose findUser customer && stripe_version ephemeralKey is: ', result);
                if(result != null) {
                    res.status(200).send({message: 'Ephemeral key created successfully.', data : result});
                } else {
                    res.status(400).send({message: 'Ephemeral key not created'});
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('Mongoose findUser customer && stripe_version ephemeralKey error: ', err);
                res.status(503).send({message: 'Internal error, Ephemeral key not created'});
            });
```

retrieve it with a method in my repository that hits the endpoint:

```
Future<String> getEphemeralKey({String apiVersion, String stripeId}) async {
    String ephemeralKey;
    await _firebaseAuth.currentUser.getIdToken().then((idToken) {
      headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'api_key': Environment.dbApiKey,
        'AuthToken': idToken
      };
    });
    var params = {'customer': stripeId, 'apiVersion': apiVersion};
    final Uri uri = Uri.http(Environment.dbUrl, 'api/users', params);

    await get(uri, headers: headers).then((resp) {
      if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
        ephemeralKey = jsonEncode(jsonDecode(resp.body)['data']);
      }
    }).catchError((e) {
      print('PaymentMongoRepository getEphemeralKey error: $e');
    });
    return ephemeralKey;
  }
```

and finally I Initialise customerSession:

```
Future<String> createCustomerEphemeralKey(
                  {String apiVersion, String customerId}) async {
                String ephemeralKey;
                await _mongoRepository
                    .getEphemeralKey(
                        apiVersion: apiVersion, stripeId: state.user.stripeId)
                    .then((key) {
                  ephemeralKey = key;
                }).catchError((e) {
                  print(
                      '∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞  AccountConnectionManager getEphemeralKey key error: $e');
                });
                return ephemeralKey;
              }

              CustomerSession.initCustomerSession(
                  (apiVersion) => createCustomerEphemeralKey(
                      apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
                      customerId: state.user.stripeId),
                  stripeAccount: state.user.stripeId);
```

The method is expecting an Ephemeral key in a json formatted string (which is not specified anywhere except in the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Failed to parse Ephemeral Key, `Please return the response as it is as you received from stripe server`
```

I discovered it looking at the actual package code for ÈphimeralKey ..
Hope this helps others..
Cheers